# Making multiple posts

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

am having problem with my above script

i need help, i want to make multiple ajax post. i have two url files and i want to send request on each of them

i want to send request and get response

and then send other post automatically after previous one on success call

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hello World! Site Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Submit").click(function(event) {
       Execute();
       
    });

    function Execute(){
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'file1.php',
        data: { 'text': $("input[name='text']").val()
        },
         success: function(res) {
    $('#result_1').text(res.msg);
    
    // after success of provious post now make this post
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'file2.php',
        data: { 'text': $("input[name='text']").val()
        },
         success: function(res) {
    $('#result_2').text(res.msg);
  }
  
  // after success now reload some part of my html div1
  function update(){
    $('#div1').load("index.html #div1");
}
setInterval( function(){
   update();
}, 1000 );
  },
  
  // stop reload or div1 updating if url: 'file2.php', success msg eq to 'thanks'
  
        error: function() {
          alert("something went bad");
        }
      });
    };

  });
</script>

  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="div1">
    <h1 id="result_1"></h1>
    <h1 id="result_2"></h1>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="Submit" value="Submit"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, perhaps check out Chrome dev tools to see the request traffic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to mention the dataType: `dataType: 'json'` in the options object:

```
function Execute(){
    let inp = $("input[name='text']").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'file1.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { 'text': inp },
         success: function(res) {
    $('#result_1').text(res.msg);
    
    // after success of previous post now make this post:
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'file2.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { 'text': inp },
         success: function(res) {
    $('#result_2').text(res.msg);
  }})}});
}
```

The following snippet demonstrates the two step AJAX action. As `POST` cannot be performed using this test-environment based on `window.URL.createObjectURL()` the `$.get()` below uses `GET` instead. The principle should be the same though:

```js
// for AJAX testing: mirror data back as a JSON string:
function echoURL(data) {
  return URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)],{type: "text/json"}));
}

$("#Submit").click(function(ev){
  $.ajax({type: 'GET', url: echoURL({msg:"first"}), dataType: 'json', 
         // data: { 'text': inp },
     success: function(res) { 
       $('#result_1').text(res.msg); 
       $.ajax({type: 'GET', url: echoURL({msg:"second"}), dataType: 'json', 
               // data: { 'text': inp },
         success: function(res) { 
           $('#result_2').text(res.msg); 
       }})
  }})
})
$('button').click(function(ev){$('h1').text("")})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
    <h1 id="result_1"></h1>
    <h1 id="result_2"></h1>
</div>
<input type="button" id="Submit" value="Submit"/>
<button>clear</button>
```

Comment: thanks much for answer, but seems incomplete because i want to relond every seconds as above shown and compere if success response eq to thanks and stop div reloading

Comment: You should be able to directly replace your `Execute()` function definition with my version. Maybe there are other issues in your remaining code. I haven't been able to test that, but the `Execute()` function should already be an improvement in any case. ;-)